# Can't install putty when I'm trying to connect it with vps

Tags: hosting, ubuntu-16.04, vps

I'm trying to connect putty with VPS, but I'm facing difficulties when I installed putty, I'm getting this error
[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, and apparently the sources.list can't be readable
Please help!